# Get a copy of a boost graph that is reversed

Tags: c++, boost

I have a

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list< boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexInfo, EdgeInfo > Graph;
```

That I want a copy of with all edges reversed. I want a copy and not a view since I want to change the edge weights of this graph without modifying the original data structure.

boost::reverse_graph gives a view (with a different type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `make_reverse_graph`:

E.g. input

```
Graph read() {
    Graph g;

    using namespace boost;
    dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", get(&VertexInfo::label, g));
    read_graphviz("digraph { a -> b; a -> c; b -> d; b -> e; e -> f; e -> c; }", g, dp);

    return g;
}
```

Graph:

[image]

Reversal:

```
int main() {
    using namespace boost;

    auto g = read();
    auto r = make_reverse_graph(g);

    write_graphviz(std::cout, r, make_label_writer(get(&VertexInfo::label, r)));
}
```

Graph

[image]

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/785a3d3583f4fcd5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/reverse_graph.hpp>
#include <libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp>

struct VertexInfo {
    std::string label;
};

struct EdgeInfo {
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexInfo, EdgeInfo> Graph;

Graph read() {
    Graph g;

    using namespace boost;
    dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", get(&VertexInfo::label, g));
    read_graphviz("digraph { a -> b; a -> c; b -> d; b -> e; e -> f; e -> c; }", g, dp);

    return g;
}

int main() {
    using namespace boost;

    auto g = read();
    auto r = make_reverse_graph(g);

    write_graphviz(std::cout, r, make_label_writer(get(&VertexInfo::label, r)));
}
```

Comment: Cool visualization that I did not know about, and all around great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
boost::copy_graph(boost::make_reverse_graph(_graph), _reverse_graph);
```

Where _reverse_graph is type Graph