# c++: Simple graphviz example for reading DOT files

Tags: c++, graphviz, dot

Does anyone have a simple example of using GraphViz to read DOT files and traverse its graph? The site's documentation doesn't seem to have any.

I should note that I cannot use Boost. I need to use cgraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have many such answers on site:

### Using Boost Graph Library

- [boost::read_graphviz - how to read out properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898195/boostread-graphviz-how-to-read-out-properties/29904324?s=1|4.9223#29904324)
- [read_graphviz() in Boost::Graph, pass to constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496182/read-graphviz-in-boostgraph-pass-to-constructor/29501850?s=2|2.6949#29501850)
- [Odd Error Importing DOT files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804075/odd-error-importing-dot-files/32812331?s=3|0.1282#32812331)
- [Get a copy of a boost graph that is reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101788/get-a-copy-of-a-boost-graph-that-is-reversed/30110392?s=4|0.0962#30110392)
- [Using two objects as hash key for an unordered_map or alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279268/using-two-objects-as-hash-key-for-an-unordered-map-or-alternatives/32281365?s=5|0.0645#32281365)
- [How does the attractive force of Fruchterman Reingold work with Boost Graph Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815336/how-does-the-attractive-force-of-fruchterman-reingold-work-with-boost-graph-libr/29822984?s=6|0.0636#29822984)

### Using `libcgraph`

Sadly I cannot find that answer ... o.O

I'm absolutely convinced I wrote an answer using that here before, because I spent considerable amount of time on it. Perhaps you have better luck finding it.

Comment: Thanks, I should've mentioned that I cannot use Boost. I need to use cgraph.

Comment: I have no clue what happened to my answer. I might ask around on meta.